# SQL How to find the date that exists or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014. I need to find all the orders that have been placed or not after they were requested. The process looks like that: we receive the request, then we can place the order instantly or after some period of time - 'ReminderDate'. The problem is that the orders sometimes are missed and I want to find a way to find them

I tried

```
SELECT 
  a.[AddedDate],
  b.[DateAdded],
  b.[ReminderDate]
FROM request a
left join order b on a.clientId=b.clientId
where a.AddedDate between '2018-11-09' and '2018-11-17'  and 
b.DateAdded>a.AddedDate  or b.clientId is null and 
a.deleted=0 and
b.deleted=0
```

But it only shows me the successfully placed ones and I know that some of them are missed. The issue is to find all orders that have AND haven't been placed too **after** request date for the given client (is it possible in one query ?).
Please tell what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Assuming I understand your logic I think you want brackets around `(b.DateAdded>a.AddedDate  or b.clientId is null)`.

Comment: Put parentheses around the OR'd condtions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it correct that you want to see the Request (`a`) even when there's no Order (`b`) for it?

I suggest you move all conditions for `b` into the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN`. This way you don't need the `b.clientId IS NULL` check either:

```
SELECT 
  a.[AddedDate],
  b.[DateAdded],
  b.[ReminderDate]
FROM request a
LEFT JOIN order b ON a.clientId = b.clientId AND b.DateAdded > a.AddedDate AND b.deleted=0
WHERE a.AddedDate between '2018-11-09' and '2018-11-17' and a.deleted=0
```

If you prefer having the conditions in the `WHERE`, you need to add brackets (as pointed out in the comments) and make sure that you always check explicitly whether you found no Order, aka `b.clientId is null`.

```
SELECT 
  a.[AddedDate],
  b.[DateAdded],
  b.[ReminderDate]
FROM request a
left join order b on a.clientId=b.clientId
where (a.AddedDate between '2018-11-09' and '2018-11-17'  and 
b.DateAdded>a.AddedDate  or b.clientId is null) and 
a.deleted=0 and
(b.deleted=0 or b.deleted is null)
```

Up to you which one you prefer. I recommend the first since it's shorter and has fewer different cases you need to think about.

Comment: It really works. I didn't know that it is possible to put any conditions before 'where' Many thanks

Comment: Glad it helped. You can indeed put any condition for the join there.

Answer (score 1):

It seems strange to me that you would want *all* orders for the client after a given date.  That becomes a mess if there are multiple orders.  I would prefer to have just the "next" one if there is one:

```
select r.AddedDate, o.DateAdded, o.ReminderDate
from request r outer apply
     (select top (1) o.*
      from order o
      where o.clientId = r.clientId and o.DateAdded > r.AddedDate and
            o.deleted = 0
      order by o.DateAdded desc
     ) o
where r.AddedDate between '2018-11-09' and '2018-11-17' and
      r.deleted = 0 ;
```

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't consider such an option. I'll try this as well. Thx